# Laurent series, complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

So I'm trying to calculate the function $$f(z) = \frac{1}{z^2+9} = \frac{1}{(z-3i)(z+3i)}$$ , $$0<|z-3i|<R$$

I tried with both substitution and partial fraction but I can't get to the correct answer, some help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z-3i=w$, then $z^2+9=w(w+6i)$ and
$$\frac{1}{z^2+9}=\frac{1}{w(w+6i)}=\frac{i}{6}\left(\frac{1}{w+6i}-\frac{1}{w}\right)$$
Knowing that $0<|w|<R$, you need to get the Laurent series around $0$ for $f(w)$. Since $\frac{1}{w}=w^{-1}$, you are left with the other term:
$$\frac{i/6}{w+6i}=\frac{1}{36}\,\,\frac{1}{1+\frac{w}{6i}}=\frac{1}{36}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(-\frac{w}{6i}\right)^k,\;\;|w|<6$$
Now replace $w$ with $z-3i$
$$f(z)=-\frac{i}{6}(z-3i)^{-1}+\frac{1}{36}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{i}{6}\right)^k (z-3i)^k,\;\;R=6$$

Comment: Why is it that you neglect the second term $w^-1$, and only calculate the laurent series for the first term?

Comment: @Stratbomber Because $w^{-1}$ is already a Laurent series! Note that you want to describe the function as the series of _integer_ powers of $w$

Comment: Huge thanks for this, been stuck with this for a long time, thanks to your answer I'm actually getting somewhere now!

Comment: @Stratbomber I'm glad for being helpful!